# How to start/stop camera's movement?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have two cameras: Camera #1 and Camera #2. 
Right from the start of the scene Camera #1 is enabled and displays the scene. After a while I'm changing to Camera #2 (enabling it so it can display the scene).

Here is my code:

```
        foreach(Camera c in  GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) 
        {

            if ((c.name == "Camera #1") && (c.transform.position.x>30))
            {
                c.enabled = false;


                foreach(Camera d in  GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) 
                {

                    if(d.name == "Camera #2") 
                    {
                        d.enabled = true;

                    }

                }
            }
```

I can change between cameras successfully, but I have a problem: Not just Camera #1 but Camera #2 also starts moving right from the beginning of the scene. So when I change to Camera #2 I can see that Camera #2 almost finished its way to his finish point.

I'd like to start Camera #2's movement only when I change to it.

How to start/stop Camera #2' movement?
OR
How to reset Camera #2's movement to its starting point?

(I'm using Camera Path Animator asset.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible issues:

- Camera #2 is not disabled from the start, so its movement executes. Solve this by disabling it in the Editor.
- Camera #2' Path Animator is not attached to Camera #2. Because of that, it will not be disabled even though Camera #2 is. Solve this by putting the Animator on Camera #2, or by disabling it movement by other means.
- Camera #2 is a child of Camera #1, thus inheriting Camera #1's translation. Solve this by moving Camera #2 out of Camera #1

Comment: Also disabled the camerapathanimator relating to Camera2 and this solved the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using an animation for the whole context (if possible). It seems you are making some kind of movie animation.

Place your cameras under a GameObject. That guy gets Animator and create an animation.

That animation will control the position and if the camera is enabled over time. The Animation curves and dopesheet allows easy and efficient control. On top of that, you can also use AnimationEvent if you need to call some external methods.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which disables the camerapathanimator and stops the movement of Camera #2 until Camera #1 reaches a specific coordinate.

1. Create new Gameobject.
2. Create 2 Camerapaths with Camera Path Animator asset
3. Set both camerapaths's "Play on start" value to TRUE
4. Create a new C# script for the Gameobject.
5. Poipulate the code below into void Update () {}

   foreach(Camera c in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) {
       if ((c.name == "Main Camera")) {
           if ((c.transform.position.z > -20)) {
               c.enabled = false;
               foreach(Camera d in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) {
                   if (d.name == "Main Camera (1)") {
                       foreach(CameraPathAnimator e in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(CameraPathAnimator))) {
                           if (e.name == "Main Camera Path (1)") {
                               e.enabled = true;
                               d.enabled = true;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           } else {
               foreach(CameraPathAnimator e in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(CameraPathAnimator))) {
                   if (e.name == "Main Camera Path (1)") {
                       e.enabled = false;
                   }
               }
               c.enabled = true;
           }
       }
   }